# Is there a word for pant sleeves?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Is there a word for pant sleeves? I know that 'sleeves' is used for sweaters, but what about pants? I don't think the phrase 'sleeve pants' is idiomatic. Is it? By pant sleeves, I obviously mean the part that covers the entire leg.

Comment: Did you try looking this up? A quick search for "what do you call pant sleeves" brought up the answer for me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

They're called legs as well, more specifically *trouser legs* or *pant legs*:

> a cloth covering consisting of the part of a pair of trousers that covers a person's leg

(source: [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/trouser%20leg))

Which one you should use [depends on the continent](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-trousers-and-pants); the clothing is usually called trousers in the UK and pants in the US, so given your question you should go with *pant legs*.

Comment: *"...the clothing is usually called trousers in the UK and pants in the US..."* Sometimes to much hilarity, as over here in the UK, *pants* (as a noun) means *underpants* (as an adjective, *pants* means *really bad*). But we know what Americans mean when they say it. :-)

Answer (score 10):

This part is the "[trouser leg](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/trouser+leg)".  I believe in American English "[pant leg](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pant+leg)" or "pantleg" is also used.

Comment: Or ["*pants* leg"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327696/pant-legs-or-pants-legs), as weird as that might sound.

Comment: @Andrew Yes. Grammatical or not, `pants leg` tends to be the most common in spoken American English everywhere I've ever lived.

Answer (score 0):

Back in Tudor times sleeves were separate items, particularly for women's dresses. They would be held on on with ribbons or buttons. So a particular word came about. At that time, pants didn't even exist. The modern-day trousers as middle class dress didn't really come about until sometime around the 18th century. Breeches would have been formal dress before then.The separate leg covering word you are looking for is "hose", knitted stockings that would cover the leg while the breeches stopped at the thigh (Tudor era) or, later on, the knee.

Comment: This isn't the word the asker is looking for at all. The asker is in the 21st century, not in Tudor times.

Comment: It's also wrong, IIRC. The reason why they're called "pants" is because they were originally two different garments: one for each leg.

Comment: It's also the wrong item of clothing. *Hose* is occasionally used these days (hence the word *hosiery* for underwear which is still in widespread use in more formal contexts such as shops) but it is more likely to be called *stockings* or *tights* for examples made from much thinner fabric, or *leggings* for something which is very similar to the original *hose*.